# toggle wrapInner with jquery

Tags: jquery

I can't seem to find a toggle method for jquery's wrap.

Simply want to toggle the wrap of the span when .toggle_comments is clicked.

```
$( document ).on('click', '.toggle_comments', function( event ){

    $( this ).closest( "p" ).wrapInner( $( "<span class='inline-comments-highlight-text'></span>" ) );

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't find it because such method doesn't exist. You could do something like:

```
var 
    spanHTML = "<span class='inline-comments-highlight-text'></span>",
    spanSel  = "span.inline-comments-highlight-text"
;

$( document ).on('click', '.toggle_comments', function( event ) {
    var $p = $(this).closest("p"),
        $span = $p.children(spanSel);

    if ( $span.length ) {
        $span.children().unwrap();
    } else {
        $p.wrapInner(spanHTML);
    }
});
```